# Tez running time slower than hive on larger dataset (~2.5 TB)

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hiveql, apache-tez

We have started to look into testing tez query engine. From initial results, we are getting 30% performance boost over Hive on smaller data set(1-10 GB) but Hive starts to perform better than Tez as data size increases. Like when we run a hive query with Tez on about 1.3 TB worth of data, it performs worse than hive alone.(~20% less performance) Details are in the post below.

http://www.jwplayer.com/blog/hive-with-tez-on-emr/

On a cluster with 1.3 TB RAM, I set the following property :

```
set tez.task.resource.memory.mb=10000;
set tez.am.resource.memory.mb=59205;
set tez.am.launch.cmd-opts =-Xmx47364m;
set hive.tez.container.size=59205;
set hive.tez.java.opts=-Xmx47364m;
set tez.am.grouping.max-size=36700160000;
```

Is it normal or I am missing some property / not configuring some property properly? Also, I am using an older version of Tez as of now. Could that be the issue too? I still to bootstrap latest version of Tez on EMR and test it and see if that could do any better

Comment: These memory settings make me a little dizzy (especially the 60 GB of RAM spent on the AM) but, out of curiosity... do you compress intermediate results (Snappy, LZ4)? when you compare TEZ to a reference MapReduce job, what were the Mapper / Reducer container sizes? was the mapper-to-reducer ratio similar? did the Reducing start "earlier" on MR side? (cf. http://fr.slideshare.net/FlinkForward/dongwon-kim-a-comparative-performance-evaluation-of-flink/15 about TeraSort, especially slide 18)?

Comment: What is the query you are running?

Comment: mappers and reducers memory settings were default. probably 1-2 GB. Reducer started after the mapper finished.

Comment: here is the query as mentioned in the blog http://www.jwplayer.com/blog/hive-with-tez-on-emr/  .................INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE table2 PARTITION(day) SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, SUM(column6), SUM(column7), SUM(column8), SUM(column9), SUM(column10), day FROM table1 WHERE day={DATE} GROUP BY column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, day;

Comment: opened a bug for it.....here are details .....  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-12683